# High quality graph/waveform display component in C#

Tags: c#, waveform

I'm looking for a fast, professionally looking and customizable waveform display component in C#.

I'm wanting to display mainly real-time audio waveforms (fast!) in both time and frequency domain. I would like the ability to zoom, change axis settings, display multiple channels, customize the feel and colors etc...

Anybody knows of anything, whether commercial or not?

Thank you!

Diego

Comment: As Gigasoft founder, see our [DirectX /Direct3D C# charting wav data demo, example 123](http://www.gigasoft.com) The demo shows exes in WinForms, WPF, and C++/MFC pure native. Real-time updated with play position of vertical line annotation showing 12M points continuously updated with no lag. Also shows an easy custom x axis of Minutes:Seconds.  Zoom-able via mouse and mouse-wheel.

Answer (score 5):

I bumped into a code project awhile ago that was doing this.

Check out http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/GraphComponents.aspx it may be what you are looking for to do real-time graphing in .net

Answer (score 2):

as far as i know, national instrument has some cool control, but it's not free.

http://sine.ni.com/psp/app/doc/p/id/psp-317

free ones:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/wavecontrol.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Based on Illaya's code:

```
public void CreateWaveForm(string audioFilePath, string audioWaveFormFilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            int bytesPerSample = 0;
            using (NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader reader = new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(audioFilePath, wf => new NAudio.FileFormats.Mp3.DmoMp3FrameDecompressor(wf)))
            {
                using (NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32 channelStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(reader))
                {
                    bytesPerSample = (reader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8) * channelStream.WaveFormat.Channels;
                    //Give a size to the bitmap; either a fixed size, or something based on the length of the audio
                    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap((int)Math.Round(reader.TotalTime.TotalSeconds * 40), 200))
                    {
                        int width = bitmap.Width;
                        int height = bitmap.Height;

                        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                        {
                            graphics.Clear(Color.White);
                            Pen bluePen = new Pen(Color.Blue);

                            int samplesPerPixel = (int)(reader.Length / (double)(width * bytesPerSample));
                            int bytesPerPixel = bytesPerSample * samplesPerPixel;
                            int bytesRead;
                            byte[] waveData = new byte[bytesPerPixel];

                            for (float x = 0; x < width; x++)
                            {
                                bytesRead = reader.Read(waveData, 0, bytesPerPixel);
                                if (bytesRead == 0)
                                    break;

                                short low = 0;
                                short high = 0;
                                for (int n = 0; n < bytesRead; n += 2)
                                {
                                    short sample = BitConverter.ToInt16(waveData, n);
                                    if (sample < low) low = sample;
                                    if (sample > high) high = sample;
                                }
                                float lowPercent = ((((float)low) - short.MinValue) / ushort.MaxValue);
                                float highPercent = ((((float)high) - short.MinValue) / ushort.MaxValue);
                                float lowValue = height * lowPercent;
                                float highValue = height * highPercent;
                                graphics.DrawLine(bluePen, x, lowValue, x, highValue);
                            }
                        }

                        bitmap.Save(audioWaveFormFilePath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: can the above code be used to generate wave from from an MP4 file?

Answer (score 1):

That is a wave flow displayer

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/wavecontrol.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check out Zedgraph. It's a free graphing library that works great. There are lots of code samples on their website that allow you to do what you're asking. [Zedgraph Downloads](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/files/) Their website seems to be having issues right now, but the download session works and contains all of their sample files.

Answer (score 1):

This will generate waveform from audio file using nAudio...

```
using NAudio.Wave;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string strPath = Server.MapPath("audio/060.mp3");
    string SongID = "2";
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(strPath);
    WriteToFile(SongID,strPath, bytes);
    Response.Redirect("Main.aspx");
    }

private void WriteToFile(string SongID, string strPath, byte[] Buffer)
{
    try
    {
        int samplesPerPixel = 128;
        long startPosition = 0;
        //FileStream newFile = new FileStream(GeneralUtils.Get_SongFilePath() + "/" + strPath, FileMode.Create);
        float[] data = FloatArrayFromByteArray(Buffer);

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1170, 200);

        int BORDER_WIDTH = 5;
        int width = bmp.Width - (2 * BORDER_WIDTH);
        int height = bmp.Height - (2 * BORDER_WIDTH);

        NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader reader = new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(strPath, wf => new NAudio.FileFormats.Mp3.DmoMp3FrameDecompressor(wf));
        NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32 channelStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(reader);

        int bytesPerSample = (reader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8) * channelStream.WaveFormat.Channels;

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {

            g.Clear(Color.White);
            Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Gray);
            int size = data.Length;

            string hexValue1 = "#009adf";
            Color colour1 = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hexValue1);
            pen1.Color = colour1;

            Stream wavestream = new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(strPath, wf => new NAudio.FileFormats.Mp3.DmoMp3FrameDecompressor(wf));

            wavestream.Position = 0;
            int bytesRead1;
            byte[] waveData1 = new byte[samplesPerPixel * bytesPerSample];
            wavestream.Position = startPosition + (width * bytesPerSample * samplesPerPixel);

            for (float x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                short low = 0;
                short high = 0;
                bytesRead1 = wavestream.Read(waveData1, 0, samplesPerPixel * bytesPerSample);
                if (bytesRead1 == 0)
                    break;
                for (int n = 0; n < bytesRead1; n += 2)
                {
                    short sample = BitConverter.ToInt16(waveData1, n);
                    if (sample < low) low = sample;
                    if (sample > high) high = sample;
                }
                float lowPercent = ((((float)low) - short.MinValue) / ushort.MaxValue);
                float highPercent = ((((float)high) - short.MinValue) / ushort.MaxValue);
                float lowValue = height * lowPercent;
                float highValue = height * highPercent;
                g.DrawLine(pen1, x, lowValue, x, highValue);

            }
        }

        string filename = Server.MapPath("image/060.png");
        bmp.Save(filename);
        bmp.Dispose();

    }
catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
public float[] FloatArrayFromStream(System.IO.MemoryStream stream)
{
    return FloatArrayFromByteArray(stream.GetBuffer());
}

public float[] FloatArrayFromByteArray(byte[] input)
{
    float[] output = new float[input.Length / 4];
    for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(input, i * 4);
    }
    return output;
}

}
```

Comment: There are a lot of superfluous variables, some miscalculations etc in Illaya's code. I'll post my cleaned up, modified version below because it's too much for the comments-box.

Comment: @Illaya Can naudio be used to generate wave form from an MP4 file ?