# GStreamer - Generate audio waveform from MP4 file

Tags: audio, command-line, gstreamer, mp4, audio-processing

I have a two-part question,

- 1) I have an MP4 file and want to generate it's audio waveform.
- 2) I have another MP4 file which has audio at channel [0] and channel [1]
   and a video track too, I want to generate waveforms for both channels as separate images.

How can I achieve both of the above by using GSteamer?

Comment: Those are both statements  :). Alos please define what you mean by a “sample point”

Comment: @szatmary actually want to generate wave form

Comment: You want an image of the wave form, or the raw PCM data?

Comment: @szatmary i want to generate the wave form from the audio of an MP4 file.

Comment: Please define waveform. What type of file do you want to have at the end?

Comment: @szatmary i actually need the sample points from the audio in the MP4 file and from that sample points i will generate the wave form.
So my question here is how to get the sample points of the audio in the MP4 file using Gstreamer.

Comment: @Harry be aware that technically "waveform" has two meanings... (1) The shape of the sound affecting how you hear it and... (2) The shape of sound if drawn visually. (3) What the heck is a _"sample point"_? In MPEG codecs language, a sample is one frame (either as picture or as MP3/AAC audio frame), how is a _"point"_ involved? (4) Why don't you just use plain English? It's not obvious if you want to add or extract (**generate**??) new audio samples into those two channels or just read them to draw audio-graph like Soundcloud does for mp3?

Comment: @Harry is it something like this?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32515073/2057709

Comment: @VC.One thats from the ffmpeg, i need the same using Gstreamer

Comment: @VC.One can you guide me on one more thing i have a capture of raw audio, i wanted to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042155/high-quality-graph-waveform-display-component-in-c-sharp , but the link uses NAudio, can we do it without using NAudio

Comment: @szatmary One can you guide me on one more thing i have a capture of raw audio, i wanted to do something like this stackoverflow.com/questions/2042155/… , but the link uses NAudio, can we do it without using NAudio

Comment: @Harry, I don't use Gstreamer. I found your question because of `MP4` tag. Are you sure Gstreamer can even do this in anyway? Why not try FFmpeg since it also runs via command-line (Win / Mac / Linux)?

Comment: @VC.One Do you work with audio? and did you see my above comment for calculating sample points without using NAudio

Comment: @Harry try my advice below. If you [**`update`**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52592052/edit) your question with a code attempt then we'll try fix what you show.

Comment: Please update your question to specify whether you want to crank out code by using the gstreamer library in your own c language code or do you wish to simply use its command line tools instead ?  also as others have requested you really should update your post with the work you have created to solve this to date ... your question is borderline too broad and should become a series of short crisp questions asking and receiving pointed answerable nuggets of knowledge which is more atune to how SO best operates

Answer (score 0):

Is the raw audio in 16-bit or 32-bit format? What is the sample rate (44100 hz) and what is time duration?

Anyways assuming 44.1khz at 10 second duration... since you can't draw 44 thousand samples as pixel width so choose a final display size (eg: width = 800px and height = 600px) and do math :

```
//# is (samplerate / duration) / width...
(44100 / 10) / 800 = 551;
```

After reading first 2 values, you will jump ahead by 551 bytes and repeat until total of (.

So in your raw data starting from `pos = 0;`...

- 1) Check this and next sample, then multiply their values together (`sample[pos] x sample[pos+1]`).
- 2) Take that result and divide by 65335 (maximum value of 16-bits or 2 bytes).
   That's the final value of your first sample or point.
- 3) Draw a line to fit according to image height (*eg:* 600px) so if `sample = 0.83` then:

  `line_height = (600 x 0.83); //# gives 498 as line height`
  `line_count += 1; //# add plus 1 to line count (stop when it reaches 800)`
- 4) Skip ahead from position `[pos]` by **+551** bytes and repeat step (1) until `line_count == 800;`